# add small image to a table view

Tags: tableview

I have a `UITableView` with a `NSMutableArray` with a lot of classes name (1A, 1B, 2A...) and I want to display the image before the text in the row. How can display the 1A image if the text in the cell is = to 1A? any idea or code example?

thanks a lot because am quite new in this world :D

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

If yes, the link above provides a tutorial on how to make your own tableviewcells, and when making such a cell you can provide yourself if you want an nsstring, uiimage or whatever shown in each tableviewcell.

Comment: thanks this helped me to understand but not to implent the method. I have some rows with the numbesr 1A, 1B...and for every row where the text.cell is = to 1 i want to display a specific image. what is the code to do this? :)

Comment: Does this link help you more?

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

cell.textLabel.text = [YourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image.jpg"];

This shows you for each cell, the same image. If you want to have a different image for a different cell, you should put all images in an array as well and write it as:

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[YourImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: ok, but how can i put the 1.png image in all the row that contain the text 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D...??

Comment: Oh I think i finally understand what you mean. You need to use NSDictionary:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Identifier];
}

//This piece of code will allow you to display your images beside your text in the tableView

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.classNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

}

I hope this helps, it worked for me. :) cheers